# DataConnection.HandleError while uploading image using upload file dialoge in kentico cms 7

Tags: kentico

when i try to upload image files using upload file, it show this error

> [DataConnection.HandleError]: Query: INSERT INTO CMS_Attachment
>   ([AttachmentID], [AttachmentName], [AttachmentExtension],
>   [AttachmentSize], [AttachmentMimeType], [AttachmentBinary],
>   [AttachmentImageWidth], [AttachmentImageHeight],
>   [AttachmentDocumentID], [AttachmentGUID], [AttachmentLastHistoryID],
>   [AttachmentSiteID], [AttachmentLastModified], [AttachmentIsUnsorted],
>   [AttachmentOrder], [AttachmentGroupGUID], [AttachmentFormGUID],
>   [AttachmentHash], [AttachmentTitle], [AttachmentDescription],
>   [AttachmentCustomData] ) VALUES ( @AttachmentID, @AttachmentName,
>   @AttachmentExtension, @AttachmentSize, @AttachmentMimeType,
>   @AttachmentBinary, @AttachmentImageWidth, @AttachmentImageHeight,
>   @AttachmentDocumentID, @AttachmentGUID, @AttachmentLastHistoryID,
>   @AttachmentSiteID, @AttachmentLastModified, @AttachmentIsUnsorted,
>   @AttachmentOrder, @AttachmentGroupGUID, @AttachmentFormGUID,
>   @AttachmentHash, @AttachmentTitle, @AttachmentDescription,
>   @AttachmentCustomData); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [] : caused
>   exception: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT
>   INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements,
>   look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not
>   allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

it happens in every page which has the upload file dialog. I have no idea about this error. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are somehow missing primary key on `CMS_Attachment` table. Try to check it and possibly add.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_Attachment] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_CMS_Attachment] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [AttachmentID] ASC
)
```

Don't forget to restart your app.

Comment: there is no primary key and i add..but still the same error.. and there is 2 foreign key ...that also i add .But still the same error